# Issues updating/setting multi value lookup columns via powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an issue updating multi-values in a lookup field via powershell

I can update a single value  lookup field as below but can't get to update if its multi- value.

As stated below when I hardcode it. It works.

No idea what 'm missing. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$array = @($realval.Split(';'))
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Count - 1; $i += 2)
{
    $word = $array[$i].Trim('#')
    $number = $array[$i+1].Trim('#')
    #$number
    "$number $word"
    #send param to GetLoolValues func to return records as SPFieldLookupValue
    $lookupvalue1 = GetLookUpValues -val $number
    #I can view the lookupvalue returned successfully
    #Write-Host $lookupvalue1
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection] $itemValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection
    #This LookupId returns 3 values like so :1,2,6
    $lookupvalue.LookupId = $number
    $itemValues.Add($lookupvalue)
    $CMRSItems["Event Type"] = $itemValues;
    #I can view the items returned successfully
    Write-Host "items:" $itemValues
    $CMRSItems.Update()
}
```

** GetLookUpValues this is how it works
I pass an ID to list items and return data of type  SPFieldLookupValue

Comment: GetLookUpValues how does that method work?

Comment: Is this the same question as this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92688/updating-multivalues-lookup-column-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013 ?

Comment: Robert this is how it works below
** GetLookUpValues this is how it works
I pass an ID to list items and return data of type  SPFieldLookupValue

Answer (score 1):

In your listed code, you declare the variable **$lookupvalue1** but further down you use **$lookupvalue** (missing the '1'). I'm assuming you changed this and forgot about it and it is still working without throwing errors because it's using an older object.

To help prevent such mistakes, you could enable [strict mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx) by adding this at the top of your script:

```
Set-Strictmode -Version Latest
```

EDIT:

```
#This LookupId returns 3 values like so :1,2,6
$lookupvalue.LookupId = $number
```

I don't see how it does. LookupId is an int. It contains a single value. As such you must assign a single value. There's no way it can return 3 values.

```
$itemValues.Add($lookupvalue)
$CMRSItems["Event Type"] = $itemValues;
```

Seeing this, you started out correctly, but adding item X to collection Y and assigning collection Y to your field, **Z** amount of times still only leaves **one** value in your field, not **Z** values, because it was overwritten each time.

What I think you want to do is loop as you are now, but keep adding the **$lookupvalue** to **$itemValues** each time and below your loop, assign **$itemValues** to **$CMRSItems["Event Type"]**

Comment: Thanks Cameron.Yeah thats right but i was trying to use only the lookupid which i declared like this :
$lookupvalue.LookupId = $number

Comment: **Thanks Cameron for the tip.
But find my problem as I was initiating the SPLookupvaluecollection  in the loop.
as soon as I took it out it working as expected.
Cheer

Comment: Your code would still be inefficient as you're assigning the current collection each time in your loop, while doing it once in the end would be sufficient, as I said in my answer.